# If I have two groups, how can I select random 50% of one group and 100% of the other group in python

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

If I have a datafame with two groups, how can I select a random 50% of the rows associated with one group, and 100% of the rows associated with the other group? This is the code so far, which will give me 50% of both groups. Thanks in advance.

```
df1=df1.sample(n=len(df1))
grouped = df1.groupby(['group'], as_index=False)
newgroups=grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5) if 'group' == 1 else x.sample(frac=1.0))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code.

Comment: I have no code - I'm not sure where to begin with this one

Comment: What data structure do you have? is that dictionary? a database?

Comment: it's a python dataframe

Comment: please share the dataframe code

Comment: I do not have any code to perform this operation currently

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)